# F# Why is int assumed as type when add / mul is performed in a function?

Tags: f#, type-inference

If I write a function in f# like so:

```
let max x y =
    if x > y then x
    else y
```

F# treats x and y as generics that need to be comparable, so I can call it with ints, and later floats, no problem.  But if I use an operator like addition:

```
let add x y =
    x + y
```

F# initially assumes x and y are ints. If I call it first with ints, then it can only be used with ints from then on. If I call it first with floats, then type inference assumes it accepts only floats from then on.  Why doesn't it treat it generically like max?

Comment: Can't answer the *why* question, but can help you fix it: use `inline`.

Comment: Ok, that is a clue. Perhaps there is a code size concern, because too many different types support the + operator?

Comment: I think the why is for speed - not having to dynamically look up which `+` to use is going to be much faster.