# F# generic method failed to parse my type specification?

Tags: parsing, generics, methods, f#

Inside fsi, I have typed:

```
> let f (x:'a) (y:'b)=x + y
- ;;

  let f (x:'a) (y:'b)=x + y
  ----------------------^

stdin(25,23): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic     
than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'b has been   
constrained to be type 'int'.

val f : x:int -> y:int -> int
```

Well, i aim to define "f" to be able to receive 2 parameters, but seems the interpreter fails to understand my need and parse f as int->int->int? Why?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447918/f-why-is-int-assumed-as-type-when-add-mul-is-performed-in-a-function that was asked earlier today

Comment: Thanks, I know it now, should be let inline f (x:'a) (y:'b)=x + y;;